# Play Service Error

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have imported the Play Service sucessfully. But now when I want to loggin in with my device there is an error called:

The Application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificat match the client Id created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not published yet, check that the account you are testing is an tester account. See log for more Information. 

But the App is correytly the Id is correyt and the package name too.
I have also two accounts one is Tester the other not.

Loact is:

```
09-08 18:04:10.223  20100-20100/? E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
09-08 18:04:10.223  20100-20100/? E/Zygote﹕ v2
09-08 18:04:10.223  20100-20100/? I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10436
09-08 18:04:10.223  20100-20100/? I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
09-08 18:04:10.233  20100-20100/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G900F_4.4.2 ver=34
09-08 18:04:10.233  20100-20100/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G900F_5.0_0014
09-08 18:04:10.233  20100-20100/? E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-08 18:04:10.233  20100-20100/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-08 18:04:10.263  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid D/TimaKeyStoreProvider﹕ TimaSignature is unavailable
09-08 18:04:10.263  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid D/ActivityThread﹕ Added TimaKeyStore provider
09-08 18:04:10.293  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid D/ResourcesManager﹕ creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid-2/base.apk
09-08 18:04:10.493  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
09-08 18:04:10.493  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
09-08 18:04:10.503  20100-20116/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
09-08 18:04:10.523  20100-20116/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
    Build Date: 03/03/15 Tue
    Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1_RB1_20150108_025_1077123_1158499
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
09-08 18:04:10.523  20100-20116/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-08 18:04:10.543  20100-20116/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0xaed22088 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 8
09-08 18:04:10.543  20100-20116/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-08 18:04:10.723  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@216b7be4 time:20690728
09-08 18:04:13.503  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid time:20693503
09-08 18:04:13.613  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid W/PopupManager﹕ You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view. Note that this may not work as expected in multi-screen environments
09-08 18:04:13.633  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid I/MediaPlayer﹕ Need to enable context aware info
09-08 18:04:13.633  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
09-08 18:04:13.663  20100-20119/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (973, 0)
09-08 18:04:13.663  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
09-08 18:04:13.673  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid I/GAv4﹕ Google Analytics 7.8.95 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
    adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
    adb logcat -s GAv4
09-08 18:04:13.693  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid W/GAv4﹕ AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled. Register the receiver for reliable dispatching on non-Google Play devices. See for instructions.
09-08 18:04:13.713  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid W/GAv4﹕ CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible. for instructions.
09-08 18:04:13.723  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
09-08 18:04:13.723  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
09-08 18:04:13.723  20100-20183/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid W/GAv4﹕ AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be delivered reliably. See  for instructions.
09-08 18:04:13.733  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
09-08 18:04:13.733  20100-20113/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (702, 0)
09-08 18:04:13.843  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@34d3307b time:20693840
09-08 18:04:22.433  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@34d3307b time:20702432
09-08 18:04:24.933  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
09-08 18:04:25.073  20100-20100/de.developer.sixtysix.hiddenandroid E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Thanks for your answers.
Tim

Comment: Kindly provide more information like your source code and manifest permissions. Also make sure you have set up consent screen on Google Developer Console and generated client id and api key with correct package name and debug.keystore

Comment: In the Sourcecode and the Manifest is all correct i think it the error is in the developer console

Comment: Don't think that there cannot be error/mistake on your side. You know how many developers use Google Console. Don't blame it for your silly mistakes.

Comment: Nonono. I think i manged something worng. I think i have the wrong setting.  When im back today i Wirte the Post with more inforamtions